# How to prevent animation from being stopped by background worker in WPF

Tags: wpf, animation

I have a WPF application that is doing some serious work (doing some calculations) when a button is hit. I wanted to add a 'busy animation'. However, the application is so busy doing its work that the animation is stopped until the calculations are finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serious work should always be handled in a separate thread otherwise the complete user interface may be blocked. So you are unable to click anything and not even close the application.

If it is possible you should also try the make small chunks of work and give the rest of the application time to "take a breath" and not do all work at once. It's not always possible but some work can be managed that way.

Comment: UI blocking is desirable. On the contrary, it is not desirable for the thread to be non-blocking and for the user to perform several time-consuming operations.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your "serious work" in the UI thread? If so, you need to move the work to a separate thread if you still want the UI to be updated.

Comment: What if the request does not refer to one of your smaller applications, but to a huge application that has some historical development and over 2.5 million lines of code?